# How to make multiple subdirectories in Eclipse from existing code

Tags: c, eclipse

I am using Windows 10 and Eclipse Mars edition 32 bit. Programming in C

I am trying to learn C from a Lynda.com course C Essential Training. The course provides a zipped directory with many .c and files and a few others like .h files as you can see below.
[image]

However in the video he managed to get each .c file and related source code into its own directory structure.

[image]

I've tried numerous type of imports and I also used a batch file to put each .c file in its own folder and tried importing that. I was able to get the Eclipse IDE project window to look like the instructors, but as soon as I tried to compile individual .c programs the project kept looking in the primary workspace folder which for me is C:\Source\Testing\workspace and error'd out.

Is there an import option to create this type of subdirectory structure automatically? I want to go through the tutorial and build and execute each .c file individually. However what I have had to do is put the .c file into a single folder build it and run it one at a time. I then have to delete the source and debug folder and start over for each lesson. There must be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse workspace is streigh connected to FS.
This means that your workspace in Eclipse is a folder on your hard disk or where it is stored.

What you can simply do is to create a new folder using right-click-popup-menu within Eclipse Project Explorer and then copy/move files into the new folder.
Or you can create a new folder into your workspace directory and copy/move file inside, then you must refresh Eclipse workspace.